# apps can't be installed on rooted device

Tags: android, rooted-device

I have brought one plus one and tried to install an app. But then it says your phone it's rooted.. Finally it didn't install. I'm aware that if a phone is rooted, then there are two disadvantage . One your phone warranty will not work if the phone is damaged while rooting. And two.. You will get support user acces .

My question is what is the problem from an application perspective, if a phone is rooted.? Why few apps are blocked to get installed on rooted phon . ?

Answer (score 0):

Functions of some apps require root access to the operating system.  For example, they might require tuning the kernel options, writing to a raw device or accessing privileged resources.

Android apps typically run in a closed "jail" to protect the system and other apps from contamination of a malicious or poorly written app.

By rooting your phone, you take the risk of this contamination on yourself.  It is why carriers will often not honor the warranty after rooting.

That being said, there are often methods of flashing back to a non-rooted version if you do need to claim a warranty.  It really depends on your skill level and patience.  If you are interested in rooting, there are many resources out there.  If it sounds scary, it probably isn't for you, and the app that requires root probably isn't something you should mess with.